# Bind checkbox in Listbox programmatically in C#/WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, checkbox, listbox, bind

Using a Listbox, how to have checkboxes for each item that can be added/removed by code , not xaml.

the Simplest example is welcome.

Comment: Sorry... I did not get you. You want to have a listbox where some items display a checkbox? And you want to add/remove this checkbox from the ItemTemplate by code?

Comment: quite right : where "each item" not some

Comment: I you can not change a template just for some items ... what you can do is to bind the visibility of the checkbox to any indicator for that. I could give you a codesample if needed. It is also possible (somehow, have to google for it also) to use different templates for different datatypes, but I would use the visibility ;-)

Comment: Indeed there is : http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-a-WP7-Checked-ListBox-in-different-ways that is simpler than the MS too much complete (but nice) example. Nevertheless, the former doesn't implement item deletion

Comment: To delete an item just remove it from the datasource of the ListView (take care that the ListView recognice this!)

Answer (score 0):

Along with checkbox, try to add some controls in the stackpanel. I hope this will help

Add a StackPanel to the grid (called InputList):

```
   for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++)
  {

    var checkbox = new CheckBox
    {
      Content = "inbox",

      HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,

      VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,

      FontFamily = new FontFamily("Calibri"),

      FontSize = 30
    };

    InputList.Children.Add(checkbox);

  }
```